# Best choice for open type font: PostScript outlines (OT CFF) or True Type outlines (OT TTF)?

Tags: fonts, opentype

I'd like to buy an open type font which is provided in two versions: with PostScript outlines (OT CFF) or with True Type outlines (OT TTF), as technical format. What would be the best choice for PDF(La)TeX/Xe(La)TeX/Lua(La)TeX use?

Comment: I haven’t studied the matter systematically, but my experience suggests that OT CFF produces smaller PDF files.

Comment: Commercial fonts normally use `CFF`. As far as I know, True Type fonts were originally designed for on-screen dispaly, and their contours use `quadratic` splines, while PostScript fonts use `cubic` splines.

Comment: @Bernard My use case will be mainly for printed documents but also for online (and maybe ePub) PDFs. Do you advise `CFF` anyway?

Comment: @Benis Bitouzé: ePub is a sort of degenerate pdf isn't it? Personally, I prefer using ‘real’ Open Type fonts ; online PDF s remain PDF s.

Comment: @Bernard ePub isn't a personal requirement :) But, apart from ePub, for PDFs mainly printed but also online, do you still advise `CFF`?

Comment: @Bernard: No; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB).

Comment: @Denis Bitouzé: Yes. I never had any problem looking at, zooming, rotating, &c. at pdf s with CFF fonts. But it's only my opinion…

Comment: @Martin Schröder: I thought ePub was some sort of pdf because Sumatra PDF (and muPDF) can also read ePub documents. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PDFTeX does not support subsetting CFF fonts; it will embed the whole font, but it can subset TrueType fonts (and Type 1 of course).

Some font foundries design their fonts in cubic (Postscript) splines and use tools that convert them to quadratic (TrueType) splines when generating TrueType fonts and this conversion might produce suboptimal splines, though this rarely makes any visible difference.

So apart from that, there should be hardly any practical difference between the two formats in this day and age.

Comment: Hence OT CFF fonts should produce bigger PDF files, contrary to Thérèse' experience, isn't it?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: If you are using PDFTeX, I guess yes.

Comment: I used a CFF font with `lualatex` and when I open the resulting pdf in Adobe Reader, every font is listed as `Embedded Subset` whether they are TrueType outlines OR CFF outlines.

Comment: @BGM: LuaTeX subsets CFF fonts.