# If both OTF and TTF variants of a font are available, which one to download/use?

Tags: fonts

I am missing [Linux Libertine font](http://www.linuxlibertine.org) on Windows. So I want to [download it](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/files/linuxlibertine/5.3.0/). It is available both as TTF and OTF.

Which one should I download and install when my intention is to use it with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Why do you want to download? The fonts are in your texsystem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, XeLaTeX stopped on it. I just updated to TeX Live 2016 on Cygwin.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200880/7883